# OS EI capitan download (getting more disk space)

Tags: macbook, disk-space, osx-el-capitan

I can't download OS EI capitan because each time it says I need more disk space. HELP PLEASE. I want it to be free when I get the disk space. PLease!

Comment: Delete some files?

Answer (score 1):

As @davidpostill said in comments, the only thing you can do is delete some stuff.

You could buy an external hard drive and move some files onto that so that you don't loose them.

**But there exists no "magic command" that will give you a few more GBs of disk space...**